# DomainService in Visual Studio 2013 using OpenRiaServices

Tags: c#, wcf, domainservices

I'm developing Silverlight Applicaton, I used Visual Studio 2010 and Visual Studio 2012.
I created DomainServices Class like this topic: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/silverlight-application-with-ria-service/

But now, i'm using Visual Studio 2013, Domain Services Class template was removed by Microsoft and replace OpenRiaServices open source .
I take along time to search How to use OpenRiaSerives in Visual Studio 2013 with no any result.

Can anybody show me step by step to Install OpenRiaServices in Visual Studio 2013 and How to used it to create DomainService class in new project? 
Thanks!

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36870056/missing-add-domain-service-class-in-visual-studio-2012-on-windows-10/49529216#49529216 for help

Comment: I have try to add this as a duplicate but I can't find the other question so please if any one can find it please add it as duplicate.